# Consider the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(a+bi) = (a,b)$. Show that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Consider the function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(a+bi) = (a,b)$.

Show that $f$ satisfies
 $[ f(\textbf{z}_1 + \textbf{z}_2) = f(\textbf{z}_1) + f(\textbf{z}_2), \,\,\, \forall \textbf{z}_1, \textbf{z}_2 \in \mathbb{C}]$

Show that $f$ is one-to-one and onto.

Find an element $\textbf{e} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\textbf{z} \textbf{e} = \textbf{z} = \textbf{e} \textbf{z}$ for all $\textbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}$. 
 Using the complex number $\textbf{e}$ you found in part (b), show that for every $\textbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, $\textbf{z} \neq 0$, there exists $\textbf{Z}' \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\textbf{z} \textbf{z}' = \textbf{e} = \textbf{z}' \textbf{z}$. Find the corresponding complex number $\textbf{z}'$ for each fixed non-zero complex number $\textbf{z}$.

My attempt I was told my argument to show it is onto is not sufficient.

(a1)
Let  $\textbf{z}_1 = a_1+ b_1i$ and $\textbf{z}_2 = a_2 + b_2i$ for some, $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2\in\mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
\textbf{z}_1+ \textbf{z}_2 &= (a_1+ a_2) + (b_1+b_2)i\\
f(\textbf{z}_1+ \textbf{z}_2) &= ((a_1+ a_2),  (b_1+b_2))\\
&= (a_1 , b_1)+(a_2,b_2)\\
&= f(a_1+b_1 i)+f(a_2+b_2 i)\\
&= f(\textbf{z}_1)+f(\textbf{z}_2)
\end{align*}

Therefore $[ f(\textbf{z}_1 + \textbf{z}_2) = f(\textbf{z}_1) + f(\textbf{z}_2), \,\,\, \forall \textbf{z}_1, \textbf{z}_2 \in \mathbb{C}]$

(a2) A function is one to one If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. Let $x=a_1+b_1i$ and $y=a_2+b_2i$  such that $x,y \in \mathbb{C}$ for some, $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2\in\mathbb{R}$

\begin{align*}
f(x) &=f(y)\\
f(a_1+b_1i) &=f(a_2+b_2i)\\
(a_1,b_1) &= (a_2,b_2)
\end{align*}
Thus $a_1$=$a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$. Hence, $x=a_1+b_1i= a_2+b_2i=y$. Therefore, the function is one to one.

Now let $z=x+yi$ such that $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ 
Now suppose $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align*}
    f(z)&=(x,y)\\
    f(x+yi)&=(x,y)\\
    (x,y)&=(x,y)\\
\end{align*}

Hence for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, \exists\textbf{z}\in\mathbb{C}$. Therefore, $f$ is onto.

(b) Let $a=a+bi$ and $e=c+di$ such that $a,e \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ 
\begin{align*}
    (z)(e)&=(z)\\
    (a+bi)(c+di)&=(a+bi)\\
    (ac-bd)+(bc+ad)i&=a+bi\\
    ac-bd&=a
\end{align*}
Thus $c=1$ and $d=0$ or $e=1+0i$. Hence clearly $(z)(e)=(e)(z)=z$

(c) Let $z'=\frac{1}{z}$ such that $z',z \in \mathbb{C}$ Now let $z=a+bi$ such that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $e=1+oi$ as defined above. 
\begin{align*}
    (z)(z')&=e\\
    (a+bi)(\frac{1}{a+bi})&=1+oi\\
    (a+bi)(\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2})&=1+oi\\
    (\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2})&=1+oi\\
    1&=1\\
    (z')(z)&=e\\
    (\frac{1}{a+bi})(a+bi)&=1+oi\\
    (\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2})(a+bi)&=1+oi\\
    (\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2})&=1+oi\\
    1&=1\\
\end{align*}

Therefore for every $\textbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}$, $\textbf{z} \neq 0$, there exists $\textbf{Z}' \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\textbf{z} \textbf{z}' = \textbf{e} = \textbf{z}' \textbf{z}$. Where $ \textbf{z}'= \frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2} \in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: you are a hard-worker ;-) That function is the identity function of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\mathbb{C}$ has just $\mathbb{R}^2$ as underlying set, so your function takes $z\in\mathbb{R}^2$ just to itself. An identity function is one-to-one and onto.

Answer (score 2):

I think a lot of what you're doing is unnecessary and off the right track.

Hint: The structure of your proof should be:

To show $f$ is one-to-one, assume $f(a+bi)=f(c+di)$ and show that $a+bi=c+di$.  To show that $f$ is onto, show that for any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, there is a $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=(a,b)$.

Comment: Yeah thats what I need clarification on because I did try to use that structure. I was told my structure for one to one was fine just my onto needed work.

Comment: It looks to me like you're proving things about group or ring structure and that the map is a homomorphism. But that takes you on a pretty big detour for proving one-to-one and onto.